# Is it possible to create a new window with mobile Chrome packaged apps?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

Can you create multiple windows on the new mobile Chrome packaged apps? I ask this because

```
chrome.app.window.create("host/index.html", 
{
  id: "host",
  bounds: {
    width: 1000,
    height: 500
  }
});
```

is working fine on desktop ([image: screenshot]) but not so great on the iOS simulator ([image: screenshot]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Chrome Apps for Mobile do not support multiple windows at the moment.

The root of the problem is that mobile devices don't have traditional window managers, per-se.

We thought about trying to simulate it with some sort of edge swipe gesture, but it raised a bunch of questions: Should we hijack gestures your application may already be using?  Should we have title bars that decrease the size of your application surface?  What if our solution does not fit with the look&feel of your application?  All hard questions to answer, so we opted not to support multiple windows for now.

On Android L-release, theres a cool new feature that was just announced that will allow applications to have multiple views ("windows") appear in the Recents switcher, so perhaps we can experiment with that.. But I think it would still be more confusing for users to switch between Recents than between windows on desktop chrome, so not sure if will be the right option for most applications.

If you want to have multiple views within your application, its best to use a web framework that helps for navigating between them within a single window.  This has actually generally been the accepted best-practice for hybrid web apps for a long time.